# Are there any repository explorer for Maven or Ivy that can be directly used from the console?

Tags: scala, maven, ivy, sbt, nexus

When creating a new project from scratch or even updating some projects, new dependencies need to be added. However sometimes one may not remember the exact name or spelling of those dependencies. So assuming one is not using the explorer from an IDE, is there a way to search or navigate the dependency repositories from the command line. This would be similar how would search application repositories in Ubuntu using aptitude search for example.
Ideally I would like to also use this from sbt.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://search.maven.org but this is of course no command line app (Web ;-()...but if you are working with Maven you should usually use at least an IDE...

Comment: How about opening it from links (or lynx) then; that's pretty close to command line

Comment: Actually I found out that there is a REST API [link](http://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-core-documentation-plugin/core/docs/index.html). A simple console app could be used to navigate it. Also there is a another repository explorer located at [link](https://repository.sonatype.org/index.html)